# Why using name with router-link is better than just using to with path?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In vue, Why is preferably using `:to="{ name: 'home'}"` rather than simply using `to:="/"`

```
<template>
   <h1>Vue 2:</h1>
   <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}">Home</router-link>
  <router-view/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html#named-routes) in router docs, these are the advantages of using name instead of path :

> - No hardcoded URLs
> - Automatic encoding/decoding of params
> - Prevents you from having a typo in the url
> - Bypassing path ranking (e.g. to display a )

Comment: Thanks Brahim, just could you explain more last advantage `"Bypassing path ranking (e.g. to display a )"`

Comment: You're welcome my bro, me also I don't understand that point, I think this is related to SEO